# Laplace equation for a trapezoidal domain

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve Laplace equation over a Isosceles trapezoidal domain.

[image]

I need an analytical solution . would you please guide me writing the code in mathematica. how to add the boundary conditions for non-parallel sides of the trapezium ?

```
    regA = Polygon[{{0,0},{1, 1}, {2, 1},{3, 0}}]

Graphics[regA]

solV = DSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,

   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y],0<=x<=1],

   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], 2<=x<=3],

   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], y == 0],

   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], y == 1]},

   u, {x, y} \[Element] regA]
```

Comment: anyone with any idea ? please guide me on how to include boundary conditions for the non-parallel sides and how to extract an analytical solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `DSolve` will be able to give you an analytical solution. 
Here is a numerical one, if you are interested.

```
regA = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}];

RegionPlot[regA, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

```
op = D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y];

BCs = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 0 <= x <= 1 && y == 0.], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], 1 < x < 2 && y == 0.],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., 2 <= x <= 3 && y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], 1 <= x <= 2 && y == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], 2 <= x <= 3 && y == -x + 3], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Exp[x]*Cos[y], 0 <= x <= 1 && y == x]};

ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, BCs}, u, {x, y} \[Element] regA]

ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regA, AspectRatio -> 0.5] // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a trick question?

```
pde = D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0

u[x_, y_] = E^x Cos[y]

pde
(*True*)
```

Satisfies the pde and bc's.

```
reg = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}];

ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Bill Watts. but could you help me with matlab? I actually did not solve pde in matlab. don't know how to insert dirichlet condition there

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Matlab.